# Merging records

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on a project in ASP.Net, and I am using SQL Server 2005. My problem is something like that:

I have two Tables.

Table A : Which has fields ID and Category (ID is primary Key)
Table B : Which has fields ID, CategoryID, Item

There is a relation A:ID ----> B.CaregoryID

Lets Add some records.

Table A:
**ID      Category**
1        Books
2        Fruits
3        Vegetables

Table B:
**ID    CategoryID      Item**
1    1                        Rytham of Music
2    1                        My Biography
3    1                        Jungal Book
4    2                        Apple
5    2                        Orenge
6    2                        Pinnaple
7    3                        Spinach

Like that there are two table and their records.

I want query something like that my final output must be in temparary table as like following

**ID                        MergeItems**
1                          **Books** -- From Table A
1                        Rytham of Music
2                        My Biography
3                        Jungal Book
2                          **Fruits** -- From Table A
4                        Apple
5                        Orenge
6                        Pinnaple
3                         **Vegetables**-- From Table A
7                        Spinach

I want to show this output in dropdown control in ASP.Net

I want a query in sql Server 2005. If you know please forword me

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were looking for a [UNION ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Category VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TableA (ID,Category) SELECT 1, 'Books'
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID,Category) SELECT 2, 'Fruits'
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID,Category) SELECT 3, 'Vegetables'

DECLARE @TableB TABLE(
        ID INT,
        CategoryID INT,
        Item VARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 1,1,'Rytham of Music'
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 2,1,'My Biography'
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 3,1,'Jungal Book'
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 4,2,'Apple'
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 5,2,'Orenge'
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 6,2,'Pinnaple'
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID,CategoryID,Item) SELECT 7,3,'Spinach'

SELECT  ID,
        MergedCategory
FROM    (
            SELECT  ID,
                    Category + ' -- From TableA' MergedCategory,
                    CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '\' AS CategoryID
            FROM    @TableA
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  ID,
                    Item,
                    CAST(CategoryID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '\' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '\'
            FROM    @TableB
        ) sub
ORDER BY CategoryID
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
Sir, it gives me correct output but, that is order by MergedCategory, right sir? I want output just as shown. I mean, according to the category. Like Books category Items must be below Books, and after that another category that is fruits and following items should be of fruit category. Like that.

   Thank you

Comment: OK, made the required changes. Added a tree path which should do the trick. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfect. 
Can you explain the use of \ in the query. 

You are the magician of sql server.

Comment: What i did wat to concat the category id with the id in a tree path structure. So Books path would be *1\* and My Biography would be *1\2\*. this will allow you to sort them using the path.